# Let $V \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be spherically symmetric and zero mean. Show $P( Z+\mu \in A) \ge P( Z+\mu \in A^c) $ and $A^c=-A$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $V \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be spherically symmetric and zero-mean random vector.

How to show that 
\begin{align}
 P( V+\mu \in A) \ge P( V+\mu \in A^c) 
\end{align}
if $\mu \in A=\{ (x_1,x_2): x_1 \le x_2\}$.

Does this inequality hold if we consider more general $A$ with the assumption that $A^c=-A$?
This inequality is what one might call `obvious'. However, I would still like formal proof of it.

I think the key is to use that $P(V\in A)=P(V\in A^c)$. 
To see that this is true note that $V= -I \, V$ in distribution, so
$P(V\in A)=P( -I \, V\in A)=P(  V\in -A)=P(  V\in A^c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set you defined, and let $\mu \in A$ I would show

$P(V + \mu \in A) \geq P(V \in A) = P(V \in A^c) \geq P(V + \mu \in A^c)$

So, for. the first one, note that if $x \in A$, then $x + \mu \in A$ for the specific set you defined for $A$. (If $x_1 > x_2$, then $x_1 + a > x_2 + b$ if $a > b$)

Similarly, if $x + \mu \in A^c$, then $x \in A^c$.

No, if you assume only assume the second thing, it will not work, Let $A = \{ (x_1, x_2): x_1 < 0\} \cup \{ (-10, 0) \} \setminus \{ (10, 0) \}$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot follow your proof. I agree with your inequalities about elements of $A$. However, I don't see how these inequalities translate to probability.

Comment: Do you agree with the fact that $A \subset B$ implies $P(A) \leq P(B)$?

Comment: yes, I agree with this fact. Where are you using this?

Comment: Let $S_1= \{ \omega \in \Omega: V(\omega) \in A \}$ and 
$S_2. = \{ \omega \in \Omega: V(\omega) + \mu \in A \} $. The argument above boiled down to showing that $S_1 \subset  S_2$ for the first inequality.

Comment: I see. Can you explain a bit better why $S_1 \subset S_2$?

Comment: So, take some $\omega \in S_1$, this means that $V(w) \in A$. Then, by the above argument, $V(w) + \mu \in A$, i.e. $\omega \in S_2$. So, every element in $S_1$ is also in $S_2$.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks.   One more question. The fact that $V$ is spherically symmetric is used on eonce when we show $P(V \in A)=P(V\in A^c)$, right?   The argument that $S_1 \subset S_2$ hods for any random variable $V$, and only uses the structure of $A$, right?

Comment: Yup. Those are both correct!

Comment: Sorry. One more.  Our discussion shows the first inequality and the second equality. To show the final inequality we have to  let   $S_2=\{ \omega: V(\omega) \in A^c \}$ and  $S_3=\{ \omega: V(\omega)+\mu \in A^c \}$, right. We need to show that $S_3 \subset S_2$, correct?

Comment: Yup. That's right.

Comment: By the way, maybe you have some intuition about this question that I posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664244/let-z-in-mathcaln0-i-and-a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-show