# Let $Z\in \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ and $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1\le x_2 \le x_3 \}$. Show $P(Z+\mu \in A) \le P(Z \in A)$ is $\mu \notin A$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):  x_1\le x_2 \le x_3 \}$.  Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a standard normal random vector.

I am trying to see if the following inequality is true
\begin{align}
P(Z+\mu \in A) \le  P(Z \in A)
\end{align} 
for all $\mu \notin A$.

**My intuition:** I am thinking of $Z$ as a ball centered at zero and $A$ as a cone starting at zero.  If we move a center of the ball farther from the cone, then the intersection (probability) should go down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is false. Consider $\mu = (0, -\epsilon, C)$ for some really small $\epsilon > 0$, and some really large $C$, which is not in $A$ for any $\epsilon, C$. Now, the probability of $Z + \mu$ being in $A$ will tend to 1/2 as $C$ grows to infinity and $\epsilon$ goes to 0. Probability $Z$ is in $A$ is exactly 1/6 though.

Comment: Isn't the probability of $Z \in A$ is equal  $1/6$.

Comment: Yes, of course; sorry for that mistake. Thankfully both 1/6 and 1/8 are less than a 1/2 :D

Comment: Also what is the intuition here?    We move along the edge of the cone, right?  I can't follow why it tends to 1/2

Comment: I think I see it. As we move along the  edge eventually everything looks if space is split into two by a plane.

Comment: Yeah, so you can visualise the gaussian as a ball, and you originally started out including only 1/6 of the ball inside. However, if you can reposition the ball such that half the ball is inside the cone, then that is a higher probability. Putting the ball on the edge of the cone away from the peak helps with that; yeah that is exactly what it looks like eventually!

Comment: Very cool. Thanks.

Comment: Here is one more question.  Where I am using this counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664365/a-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-1-le-x-2-le-x-3-b-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-2-le-x-1-le-x-3

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but what are all these questions for? This next one you are linking looks indeed true; it follows from a symmetry argument (I am sure someone will write it up), but I am quite tired of solving these progressively harder questions :D.

Comment: Thank you for your question.  I am trying to understand how the probability of normal distribution behaves on the cones.  It's very interesting and sometimes a bit counterintuitive (at least for me).  Anyway, thanks for your help with these.  I have learned a lot.